# How to insert an array into another one using slices

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I want to create a large `NumPy array` (`L`) to hold the result of some operations. However, I can only compute one part of `L` at a time. Then, to have `L`, I need to create an array of zeros of shape `L.shape`, and fill it using these parts or subarrays. I'm currently able to do it, but in a very inefficient way.

If the shape of `L` is `(x, y, z, a, b, c)`, then I'm creating `a` NumPy arrays of shape `(x, y, z, 1, b, c)` which correspond to the different parts of `L`, from part `0` to part `a-1`. I'm forced to create arrays of this particular shape due to the operations involved.

In order to fill the array of zeros, I'm creating one `Pandas DataFrame` per subarray (or part). Each dataframe contains the indices and the values of one subarray of shape `(x, y, z, 1, b, c)`, like this:

```
index0 | index1 | index2 | index3 | index4 | index5 | value
------------------------------------------------------------
     0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 | 434.2
     0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      1 | 234.5

..., and so on.
```

Because of the shape `(x, y, z, 1, b, c)`, `index3` can only contain zeros. So, there's a change to make before the values can be inserted at the right index of `L`: the column at `index3` will contain only `0s` for the first subarray, only `1s` for the second subarray, etc. So, `df['index3'] = subarray_number`, where `subarray_number` goes from `0` to `a-1`. Only the `column` at `index3` is changed.

So, the fifth subarray represented as a dataframe would look like this:

```
index0 | index1 | index2 | index3 | index4 | index5 | value
------------------------------------------------------------
     0 |      0 |      0 |      4 |      0 |      0 | 434.2
     0 |      0 |      0 |      4 |      0 |      1 | 234.5
...
   x-1 |    y-1 |    z-1 |      4 |    b-1 |    c-1 | 371.8
```

After this, I only have to iterate over the rows of each of the dataframes using `iterrows`, and assign the values to the corresponding indices of the array of zeros, like this:

```py
for subarray_df in subarrays_dfs:
    for i, row in subarray_df.iterrows():
        index0, index1, index2, index3, index4, index5, value = row
        L[index0][index1][index2][index3][index4][index5] = value
```

The problem is that converting the arrays to dataframes and then assigning the values one by one is expensive, especially for large arrays. I would like to insert the subarrays in `L` directly without having to go through this intermediate step.

I tried using slices but the generated array is not the one I expect. This is what I'm doing:

```
L[:subarray.shape[0], :subarray.shape[1], :subarray.shape[2], 
  subarray_number, :subarray.shape[4], :subarray.shape[5]] = subarray
```

What would be the right way of using slices to fill `L` the way I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not very clear, but maybe you can adapt something from this code snippet. It looks to me like you are generating your L array, shape (x, y, z, a, b, c), by computing `a` slices, of shape (x, y, z, b, c), equivalent to (x, y, z, 1, b, c). Let me know if I am completely wrong.

```
import numpy as np

L = np.zeros((10, 10, 10, 2, 10, 10)) # shape (x, y, z, a, b, c)

def compute():
    return np.random.rand(10, 10, 10, 10, 10)  # shape (x, y, z, b, c)

for k in range(L.shape[3]):
    L[:, :, :, k, :, :] = compute() # Select slice of shape (x, y, z, b, c)
```

Basically, It computes a slice of the array (part of the array) and place it at the desired location.

One thing to note, an array of shape `(x, y, z, a, b, c)` can quickly get out of hand. For instance I naively tried to do `L = np.zeros((100, 100, 100, 5, 100, 100))`, resulting in a 373 Gb RAM allocation.. Depending on the size of your data, maybe you could work only on each slices and store them to disk when the others are not in use?

Following my comment, some snippet for you to get this dimension problem:

```
import numpy as np

L = np.zeros((10, 10, 10))
L.shape # (10, 10, 10)
L[:, 0, :].shape # (10, 10)
L[:, 0:3, :].shape # (10, 3, 10)
```

The slice on `:` selects all, the slice on `x:y` selets all from `x` to `y` and the slice on a specific index `k` selects only that 'line'/'column' (analogy for 2D), and thus returning an array of dimension `n-1`. In 2D, a line or column would be 1D.

Comment: Hi, the shape is `(x, y, z, 1, b, c)`, 6 dimensions. What I've been trying to do is almost exactly what you suggest and it leads to an incorrect result. With the operations I describe in the post, I can generate the array I need but with the cost of having to represent the subarrays as dataframes first.
Exactly because a 6D array can get out of hand quickly is that I need to do the computation in parts. My final result fits in memory, but I can't deal with the overhead of computing it at once (I've got 600GB of RAM and it's not enough). I'm forced to do it this way and reconstruct later.

Comment: If `L` were 4-dimensional of shape `(x, y, z, a)` instead, I would be generating parts of shape `(x, y, 1, a)`. The dataframes would have 4 columns instead of 6, and I'd need to modify the indices of column `index2` (the index corresponding to shape `1`) according to the subarray number.

Comment: @Daniela Ok so you're mistake is very simple. You need to get rid of the `1` :) Basically, when you select a slice like this `L[:, :, :, k, :, :]` is is not 6 dimensions but 5! That's how numpy works. So when you get a computation function which returns an array `result` of shape `(x, y, z, 1, b, c)`, add one more line at the end: `result = result[:, :, :, 0, :, :]` which will get rid of the additional (useless) dimension os shape (1, ) by selecting the slice `[0]` (the only slice) from this useless dimension. Then you can put this `result` of dim 5 in the array `L` in the slice of dim 5.

Comment: That explains everything. Thanks, it worked wonders! :)